# Force all sound to one side on headset

Tags: bluetooth, headphones, zoom.app

I would like to force all sound to the left speaker on my headset.

This is easy when I am using a browser to watch YouTube:

[image: Mac Sound preferences showing that I can push the balance to the left speaker]

But when I start Zoom, the ability to balance is turned off:

[image: Mac sound preferences showing that balance is turned off when Zoom is active]

How can I override Zoom and force all the sound to the left speaker on the headset?

This is important to me because I have a hearing impairment and having sound in my right ear causes additional tinnitus.  Being able to use a headset that has silence my right ear has been a great relief.

Here are the things I have tried:

1. I contacted Zoom and had a 1 hour call with them about them disabling balance.  They basically said they were too busy to change it.
2. I contacted Bose and asked them to change their software to allow the headset to override the computer settings using the headset firmware; no response.
3. Looking thru Zoom settings for anything that will allow to to control balance; there is nothing.
4. Looking thru the Zoom settings and setting **Speaker** to **Same as system**.

[EDIT] I tried switching back to **MacBook Pro Speakers** and they allow balance even when in Zoom.  This is not a solution as I want to use my noise cancelling headset; not my speakers.

Steps to reproduce:

1. ensure Zoom is not running.
2. connect Bluetooth headset (I use Bose)
3. open **Sound Preferences** and observe that you are allowed to balance
4. start Zoom
5. observe that ability to balance is disabled
6. switch to built in speakers
7. observe ability to balance is available.
8. switch back to Bluetooth
9. observe ability to balance is not available.
10. stop Zoom
11. observe that ability to balance is restored.

Comment: dont know if it would help, but can you try changing your microphone? i mean when you use zoom, try using a microphone other than the bose one, it might resolve the issue

Comment: You can try with accessibility to force monophonic sound and the  balance to the side you want.

Comment: @PtitXav  Good thought but balance is turned off when zoom is active.

Comment: Can you use Zoom on the web? It shouldn't be able to cause this when used there.

Comment: @Ezekiel No.  The degraded experience of using zoom from a browser is not an option.

Comment: Is a different audio device possible? For example, AirPods, if only one is inserted into your (left) ear, you'll only ever have audio on the left side. What about the speakers? In testing this just now on my own MacBook Pro, I did not lose ability to change balance on the built-in speakers when a Zoom meeting was running. Balance settings are only lost when using Zoom with BlueTooth audio (even with AirPods).

Comment: It seems you have found a solution. Please submit your solution as an "Answer" instead of editing it into the original question. This allows users to upvote your solution as the proper answer so that when other users have a similar problem that can use your "Answer" as a possible solution.

Comment: @agarza There is no solution.  There is no solution where I can balance the audio with my noise cancelling headset while zoom is running.